# 1em is not set as 16px

Tags: css, font-size

i'm working on a website where the client wants some titles at 0.875em.

I checked online, and the base em unit should be 16px for modern browsers.
Well, if I set the text-size to 1em in chrome developer, it's set at 12px instead of 16px.

Tried setting `body{font-size:100%}` at the beginning. No luck.

How do I put it back at 16px base?

Comment: NEVER assume 1em = 16px.  You can only ever assume that 1em = browser default font-size on the body (or html) element.  Many browsers happen to choose 16px as their default font-size, but there are users who can and will adjust this (typically for accessibility reasons).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is because Chrome's default font-size is 12px. You should set the body and/or html element's font-size to 16px, like so:

```
html, body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

This is assuming that there's no parent elements that change this font-size though, as em is a relative size to the nearest parent that sets a size. Check into [rem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#rem) if you want an absolutely sized font, however this isn't supported in older browsers so you'll need to provide a fallback.

Comment: Tried that. Funny thing is that if I set it somewhere else, it's 16px.

Comment: What do you mean by "somewhere else"? Also, make sure there's no CSS reset after you set the body font-size.

Comment: The description “client wants some titles at 0.875em” does not justify setting any font size in pixels.

Comment: "How do I put it back at 16px base?" This is what I see as the heart of his question, and what I'm addressing. Relying on the default browser size is going to backfire with inconsistent support browser to browser.

Comment: Chrome default font-size is 16px.

Comment: Go to chrome://settings/ > Web contents > font size. Set it to `medium`. Note: Setting the `font-size` to a fixed `px` value for `html`, `body` or any other "big parent" element is not recommended if you want to comply responsive web design recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

To address what you describe as client request, set `font-size: 0.875em` on those titles. It’s odd to want to use reduced font size for headings, but maybe there’s an explanation.

This has nothing to do with your idea of 1em as equalling 16px. The `em` unit, when used for `font-size`, stands for the font size of the parent element. Nothing more, nothing less.

You might need to ask the client what they really want.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the problem.

The font-size in em is additive.

The problem is that if the base is 16px and I set a child to 0.875em, and another child is also set to 0.875em, it's gonna set the size to 0.875em of 0.875em of 16px.

You have to set the immediate parent to the exact size you want. So in my case, set the parent to 16px, to reset. Then the immediate child to 0.875em.

Comment: It is multiplicative. as it's going to be 0.875 * 0.875 * 16px

If you want a unit that is consistent across the page use rem, it stands for "root em".